# AWS S3 file upload Get 400 error code while file upload- Pinterest API

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, axios, request

I want to create a pin with Pinterest API, So I followed official [docs](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/redoc/martech/#operation/register_media_upload_POST).

So I created a post request with this code snippet:

```
 const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://pinterest-media-upload.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/',
    headers: {},
    formData: params,
    file: {
      value: fs.createReadStream(file.location),
      options: {
        filename: file.name,
      },
    },
  }
request(options, function (error, response) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error)
    console.log(response)
    console.log(response.statusCode)
})
```

Btw, my options output like that:

```
{
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://pinterest-media-upload.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/',
  headers: {},
  formData: {
    'x-amz-date': '20220214T010341Z',
    'x-amz-signature': '784024caf758eae76b1bfb3f61e31aa6ffaed6882867450c6d777ef5f09defa0',
    'x-amz-security-token': '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',
    'x-amz-algorithm': 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256',
    key: 'uploads/ab/14/d3/2:video:1142647874115387016:5215251022217270581',
    policy: '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',
    'x-amz-credential': 'ASIA6QZJ64OPDEAU3F4A/20220214/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request',
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
  },
  file: {
    value: ReadStream {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 1,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      path: '/Users/akasaa101/Desktop/vas-project/social-service/temp/VIIcz8eR6y.mp4',
      fd: null,
      flags: 'r',
      mode: 438,
      start: undefined,
      end: Infinity,
      autoClose: true,
      pos: undefined,
      bytesRead: 0,
      closed: false,
      [Symbol(kFs)]: [Object],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kIsPerformingIO)]: false
    },
    options: { filename: 'VIIcz8eR6y.mp4' }
  }
}
```

But I get an error as :

```
 '<Error><Code>InvalidArgument</Code><Message>POST requires exactly one file upload per request.</Message><ArgumentName>file</ArgumentName><ArgumentValue>0</ArgumentValue><RequestId>VZ5RH6P8MD14E6CP</RequestId><HostId>loa5iyjv2L3yRHhK0nsu4pIa1VqmvKn9nxgRs2euKlUaZ2mS5Emb0KUGolNeKDu3upY2VPxN8Zo=</HostId></Error>',
```

By the way, I tried to send the same request with axios but I get a different error.
But now I get an error as "POST requires exactly one file upload per request.".
I checked my options but I cannot find any error on my code snipped.
How can I solve this problem? Please Help!

Comment: What is `request`? Is it [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)? If so, did you take note of the big, red deprecation notice?

Comment: I think `file` should be part of your `formData`, not adjacent to it